# Deploy Angular 5 application on Linux Server

Tags: linux, angular, deployment

I am new to deploying angular application on Linux, I used to do it on IIS which was pretty simple. I have a Linux server which I access through Putty. I want to deploy my angular 5 application on this server. I have performed following steps till now

> 1. Run ng build --prod
> 2. Copy the files in dist folder on one of the folder on linux server through pscp

Now, when I am trying to access the folder like http://hostname/folderPath/index.html, nothing comes up. I know I am missing some steps, could anyone please help me in deploying the application.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or guide link?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **base** tag from **index.html** that's it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Angular App</title>
<base href="/">
Some more code
Don't do anything to this
```

After Removing Your code will like this

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular App</title>
    Some more code
    Don't do anything to this
```

Comment: I removed it but no luck :(

Comment: There is no error in console. The browser is showing The page can't be displayed.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the base... @GaganJaura, since your app is in a different folder path you should be using `<base href="/folderPath">`

Comment: @penleychan I tried that too but did not work. I think that I need to open a port to listen so that I my app could run

Comment: @GaganJaura, curious did you set up url rewrite?

Comment: @nitishk72 The index.html file has basic stuff which is created by default. I have not touch it.

Comment: @penleychan No. I did not.

Comment: @GaganJaura If you will remove that base tag then also it's fine because HTML by default start loading assets from current directory where HTML file is.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion you said you haven't set up URL rewrite rules.

Depending what you are using to host your application, you need to setup URL rewrite rules.

See [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

For linux servers

Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

NGinx:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and will let you know.

Comment: Where should I write these rules?

Answer (score 0):

don't remove "base href" it won't work
Do this it worked for me:

```
<base href="" />
```